# Help! Baking soda/water stain on finished wood countertop!

Tags: wood

I soaked strawberries in a bowl with water and baking soda to clean them, ten minutes later I came back and realized the bowl was cracked and had been leaking. This stain is the result. Wooden countertops have some sort of glossy finish to them. Freaking out.  Any tips to get rid of this?

[image: Wooden worktop with water stain]

Answer (score 0):

Some substances, such as those in some types of wood (and also in red cabbage), are natural [pH indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator). [Logwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haematoxylum_campechianum), for example, darkens from yellowish to purple as pH changes from acid to alkaline.

It *might* be that the baking has darkened the wood by making it alkaline.

An easy fix for that would be to cover the whole surface with dilute vinegar (perhaps 20% vinegar, 80% water, i.e., ~1% acetic acid), which would make the pH more acidic (though it might make the whole surface a little bit lighter). To get the vinegar to stay in place, cover the counter with paper towels and spray on the vinegar. Let stand for an hour or two, but move the towels a bit to avoid missed spots.

Of course, the stain might be from strawberry juice... If vinegar fails, follow up with a similar, *more dilute*, chlorine bleach wash (perhaps % liquid bleach to 95% water).

Answer (score -1):

To remove a baking soda water stain from a wood countertop, you can follow these steps:

- Make a mild cleaner by mixing warm water and a few drops of dish soap in a bowl.
- Dip a clean cloth or sponge in the soapy water and wring it out so it is damp, not wet.
- Wipe the stain gently with the damp cloth or sponge. Avoid scrubbing too hard, as you might damage the wood finish.
- Dry the countertop well with a clean, dry cloth.
- Check for any residue left on the area. If the stain is still there, you may need to repeat the process or try other methods.
- For persistent stains, you can use a vinegar solution. Mix equal parts white vinegar and water, dampen a cloth with it, and wipe the stain gently. Dry the area well afterward.
- For stubborn stains, you can use a baking soda paste. Mix baking soda with water to make a paste, apply it to the stain, and let it sit for a few minutes. Then rub it gently with a soft cloth, wipe away any residue, and dry the countertop.